# How to drop null fields in nested dataframe struct?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have dataframe 1, a nested dataframe with one struct column "value" with the following schema.

```
value
DateTimeRequested: "2022-09-14T16:16:00.795858+00:00"
FunctionAppDirectory: "C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot"
FunctionDirectory: "C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps"
FunctionName: "KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps"
InvocationId: "12345"
Operations: 
    KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps: 
        Request: 
            Data: 
                Applicant: 
                    Address: 
                        0: 
                            City: "Random City"
                            Country: null
                            Line_1: "123 Random Blvd"
                            State: "WA"
                            Type: null
                            Zip_Code: "12345"
                    Applicant_Type: "No"
                    Dob: "1990-01-01"
                    Economic_Activities: 
                        0: 
                            Employer: null
                            Income_Amount: 
                                Amount: 165000
                            Occupation: "Other Occupation"
                            Ownership_Percentage: 0
                            Supporting_Documents: 
                                0: 
                                    Issuing_State: ""
                    First_Name: "First"
                    Id: "APP-0000000000"
                    Last_Name: "Last"
                    Middle_Name: "M."
                    Primary_Email: "firstlast@gmail.com"
                    Primary_Phone: "1234567890"
                    Primary_Phone_Type: "Mobile Phone"
                    SSN: "111111111"
                    primary_email_type: null
                Business: 
                    Address: 
                        City: ""
                        Country: null
                        Line_1: ""
                        State: ""
                        Type: null
                        Zip_Code: ""
                    Name: ""
                Custom_Data: 
                    String_1: ""
                    String_2: ""
                    String_3: "6"
                    String_4: null
```

I also have dataframe 2, a nested dataframe with one struct column "value" with the following schema.

```
value
DateTimeRequested: "2022-09-29T23:00:16.684146+00:00"
FunctionAppDirectory: "C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot"
FunctionDirectory: "C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps"
FunctionName: "KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps"
InvocationId: "12345"
Operations: 
    KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps: 
        Request: 
            Data: 
                Applicant: 
                    Address: 
                        0: 
                            City: "Random City"
                            Country: "USA"
                            Line_1: "123 Random Drive"
                            State: "TX"
                            Type: "HOME"
                            Zip_Code: "12345"
                    Applicant_Type: "NEW"
                    Dob: "1990-01-01"
                    Economic_Activities: null
                    First_Name: "First"
                    Id: "1111111"
                    Last_Name: "Last"
                    Middle_Name: "M."
                    Primary_Email: "firstlast@gmail.com"
                    Primary_Phone: "1234567890"
                    Primary_Phone_Type: "MOBILE"
                    SSN: "123456789"
                    primary_email_type: "PERSONAL"
                Business: null
                Custom_Data: 
                    String_1: "Finance Factory"
                    String_2: "5"
                    String_3: null
                    String_4: null
```

I have a case where I have a delta table created with the schema from dataframe 1 above. In some instances I have data that has the schema of dataframe 2, that I need to merge into the delta table that has the schema of dataframe 1. Unfortunately, I am unable to simply append the data from dataframe 2 into dataframe 1, since the Economic_Activities field in dataframe 2 is null and does not match the Economic_Activities field in dataframe 1, since in dataframe 1 that field is a nested struct. Below is the pyspark error I receive when attempting to append dataframe 2 to dataframe 1.

```
AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'value' and 'value'. Failed to merge fields 'Operations' and 'Operations'. Failed to merge fields 'KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps' and 'KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps'. Failed to merge fields 'Request' and 'Request'. Failed to merge fields 'Data' and 'Data'. Failed to merge fields 'Applicant' and 'Applicant'. Failed to merge fields 'Economic_Activities' and 'Economic_Activities'. Failed to merge incompatible data types ArrayType(StructType(StructField(Employer,StringType,true),StructField(Income_Amount,StructType(StructField(Amount,LongType,true)),true),StructField(Occupation,StringType,true),StructField(Ownership_Percentage,DoubleType,true),StructField(Supporting_Documents,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(Issuing_State,StringType,true)),true),true)),true) and StringType
```

I am able to get around this error by dropping the nested Economic_Activities field in dataframe 2 with this pyspark code below.

```
df = df.withColumn(
"value",
col("value").dropFields(
    "Operations.KafkaTriggerCoreApprovedApps.Request.Data.Applicant.Economic_Activities"
),
```

)

However, in that code snippet I am explicitly specifying that the nested field to drop from dataframe 2 is Economic_Activities. I would like to find a way to programmatically drop any nested field within a struct type if that field is null, regardless of the level of nesting within the struct. Is there a way I can achieve this recursively to drop any nested field within the struct that is null, without having to explicitly specify the name of the nested field like in the code above?